# Update rails view when response comes in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, api

I'd like to do this:

```
In the view, have a button_to "Find"
The button click submits the search query to the rails action (controller)
The action calls some external api
A response comes back in 1ms up to 20secs (who knows? it's an external webservice, right?)
When the response is returned, the view which originally contains the button_to and the search field is updated with the response (via javascript)
```

1. What's the basic idea behind this?
2. What's this called?
3. How do I update the view when the response is returned?

Thanks

Comment: see http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque (how to process in bkgr) and http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye (how to update the page based on server-side event) for inspiration. There other mechanisms and libraries out there, but this will give a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you want to change the very page that made the request, your button will trigger an AJAX call. On server-side, you just have to use a lib like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to make your calls, wait for the response to hit the server, process it as you need, then send a response yourself.
2. AFAIK this action has no specific name ; however we could say that your server act as a *proxy* for another service, and if you reprocess the answer from many different APIs, well, your service is a kind of *aggregator*
3. To update the view, it depends on how you implement your ajax call. You can either :

   - respond some with JSON data, that your callback will process and use to update the page, possibly using a templating system like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
   - respond with some JS, typically a snippet that will get executed on the client like

     $('#my_element').replaceWith('<%= j( render partial: "some_partial" ) %>');